# How to trigger backup creation at different server

Tags: sql-server

I have two servers (let's say server A and server B). At server A, there is an database which is just an restored backup of same database from server B.

I would like to have an stored procedure/job/script/whatever at server A, which would allow me to

1. create an backup of that database at server B
2. restore it at server A

The tricky part is that I do not want to have any linked server between these servers... So my problem is that I have no idea how can I trigger backup at server B, from Server A. The only thing which is coming into my mind is to create some account with limited privileges at server B, save credentials in the table at server A. Than use `Backup-DbaDatabase` dbatools' function to create such backups remotely. But... it does not seems to be a good practice to keep SQL credentials exposed in the table...

Do you have maybe some ideas how to achieve something like that?

Comment: How frequently do you want this to occur and can the servers see each other or a shared NAS?

Comment: These servers can see each other, and do have access to the same shared drive. So the restore part  is not an issue. It should not be an frequent action but it is hard to tell if it is more once per week or once per 3 months. The goal is to have that 'on demand' with the newest data (daily backups are not good enough).